# content_tag generating weird html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have this snippet in a presenter:

`html << helpers.content_tag(:li, class: 'dropdown-header') do 
        helpers.content_tag('span', "Status: #{online_srt}", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-off')
      end`

and the generated html is this

`<li class="dropdown-header">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off">::before Status: Online</span>
</li>`

which makes the output to look pretty weird

[image]

the 'Online' String has a lot of spaces after the 'Status', and this makes no sense. I think the `::before` is the one responsible for this...what can I do to make the output be printed without this ::before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some pseudo-element, like `.glyphicon:before` in your css files.

Do you use twitter bootstrap? It suggest another way to use glyph icons. You need to put text after `span` tag, like

```
<li class="dropdown-header">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Status: Online
</li>
```